# How to get new mails periodically with MailCore

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I am preparing the iOS(iPhone and iPad) mail application using the MailCore framework. I want to fetch the mails periodically from the server for all the folders. Is there any procedure to ping the server periodically and check the arrival of the new mails. So that Whenever new mail comes it will load in the INBOX.(As NSTimer does not work for it).

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked into IDLE?  But be warned, if you are trying to create background push, you're going to need server side infrastructure. (Think Sparrow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an NSTimer that fires at whatever interval you want.

Answer (score -1):

The solution of your problem is [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Check the following link.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/124159/Hour-21-Building-Background-Aware-Applications

Answer (score -1):

Sorry mandeepd, UILocalNotification is not a solution, as iOS may or may not deliver notifications to your app. If it does not deliver the notification, your app have no way to check emails.

Please see this article [UILocalNotification Demystified](http://thekspace.com/home/component/content/article/62-uilocalnotification-demystified.html) for clarification.

Comment: @K S you should have commented your thoughts on @mandeep-dhiman 's answer, instead of creating it as an answer. Your answer does not provide any solution to OP.